# .reset() clears form but doesn't remove validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form in which I have a password field, and when the form is submitted, I want to reset the form. From Googling and reading docs, it looks like `.reset()` should set all values to null and make everything `pristine` and `untouched`. However, mine still has the `ng-touched` and `ng-invalid` classes on it when I hit reset. I'm not sure where I may be going wrong? In it's most minimal form I have:

```
<form [formGroup]="newPassForm" (submit)="submitNewPass()">
    <div class="row">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Password:</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="password" formControlName="currentPass">
        </mat-form-field>
        <div *ngIf="invalidPass" class="notice notice-error">Wrong password</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

With my controller as

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.newPassForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        currentPass: [
            '',
            [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]
        ],
    });
}

submitNewPass() {
    this.newPassForm.reset({ currentPass: '', newPass: '' });
    return;
}
```

I also tried it with the material stuff removed, but it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
<form [formGroup]="newPassForm" #f="ngForm">
  ...
</form>
```

ts:

```
@ViewChild('f') myNgForm;

submitNewPass() {
    this.myNgForm.resetForm({ currentPass: '', newPass: '' });
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-stepper-single-form-swaqh5)

Comment: If I get rid of the submit, then it won't ever trigger `submitNewPass()`. I assume you meant to leave it there?

Comment: updated, no you said you want to reset your form but still validators are here, try this and there will be no validators.

Comment: Yah, but the way you have it coded, `submitNewPass()` will never fire. You haven't indicated how it would submit, and in fact imply I should remove the submission method I currently have.